# How should I port this struct of C function pointers to a C# .NET implementation

Tags: c#, c, .net, struct, delegates

I'm working on porting a bootloader host library that is normally written in C/C++ for WIN32 over to a C# Class Library (rather than having to use interop with the original library, hopefully making it easier to work with and debug).  As someone not very familiar with OOP, I'm trying to figure out how to implement this specific functionality of the library to C# .NET (VS2019, .NET Standard 2.0)

In the original C library, we have the following struct in a header file of the library source code:

```
typedef struct
{
    /* Function used to open the communications connection */
    int (*OpenConnection)(void);
    /* Function used to close the communications connection */
    int (*CloseConnection)(void);
    /* Function used to read data over the communications connection */
    int (*ReadData)(uint8_t*, int);
    /* Function used to write data over the communications connection */
    int (*WriteData)(uint8_t*, int);
    /* Value used to specify the maximum number of bytes that can be transfered at a time */
    unsigned int MaxTransferSize;
} CommunicationsData;
```

This is called by the internal library functions like so:

```
static CommunicationsData* g_comm;

int Bootloader_TransferData(uint8_t* inBuf, int inSize, uint8_t* outBuf, int outSize)
{
    int err = g_comm->WriteData(inBuf, inSize);

    if (CYRET_SUCCESS == err)
        err = g_comm->ReadData(outBuf, outSize);

    if (CYRET_SUCCESS != err)
        err |= CYRET_ERR_COMM_MASK;

    return err;
}
```

The idea is that the library itself is communication protocol agnostic, and the application that uses the library is where you write the implementations of OpenConnection()/CloseConnection()/ReadData()/WriteData() as well as provide a value for MaxTransferSize.  In a C# application that uses the original C library with interop, it's done like so:

```
class Bootloader_Utils{
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate int OpenConnection();
    
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate int CloseConnection();
    
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate int ReadData(IntPtr buffer, int size);
    
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate int WriteData(IntPtr buffer, int size);
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Structure used to pass communication data down to the unmanged native C code
    /// that handles the bootloading operations.
    /// </summary>
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct CommunicationsData
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Function used to open the communications connection
        /// </summary>
        public OpenConnection OpenConnection;
        /// <summary>
        /// Function used to close the communications connection
        /// </summary>
        public CloseConnection CloseConnection;
        /// <summary>
        /// Function used to read data over the communications connection
        /// </summary>
        public ReadData ReadData;
        /// <summary>
        /// Function used to write data over the communications connection
        /// </summary>
        public WriteData WriteData;
        /// <summary>
        /// Value used to specify the maximum number of bytes that can be transferred at a time
        /// </summary>
        public uint MaxTransferSize;
    };
}
```

Then you would create a new CommunicationsData object in the Application code and assign the methods:

```
Bootload_Utils.CommunicationsData comm_data = new Bootload_Utils.CommunicationsData();
    
comm_data.OpenConnection = OpenConnection;
comm_data.CloseConnection = CloseConnection;
comm_data.ReadData = ReadData;
comm_data.WriteData = WriteData;
comm_data.MaxTransferSize = 64;
```

Then the methods are defined in the C# application like this example for OpenConnection():

```
public int OpenConnection()
{
    int status = (int)ReturnCodes.CYRET_SUCCESS;

    if (ConnectionStatus == false)
    {
        try
        {
            serialPort.Open();
            ConnectionStatus = true;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            ConnectionStatus = false;
            SetText(tb_StatusLog, " Error in opening serial port: " + exc.Message + "\r\n");

            serialPort.Close();
        }
    }
    return status;
}
```

How should I replicate this behavior in C#?  My thought was something like:

```
public class CommunicationData
{
    delegate int OpenConnection();
    delegate int CloseConnection();
    delegate int ReadData(ref byte[] dataBuf, int numBytes);
    delegate int WriteData(ref byte[] dataBuf, int numBytes);
    int MaxTransferSize { get; set; }
}
```

I could then create a new instance of this class in the library and call the method:

```
CommunicationData g_Comm = new CommunicationData();
int err = g_Comm.OpenConnection();
```

but this can't be quite right because it still wants a definition for OpenConnection(), which I want to be in the Application, not the library.

Am I on the right track here?  How can this functionality be replicated in a .NET class library?

Comment: In C#, or any object-oriented language, you'd use virtual functions rather than function pointers.

Comment: A particular problem with your `public class CommunicationData` example is that the keyword delegate, which you use 4 times, makes a type definition.  It doesn't declare a variable of that type.

Comment: @BenVoigt so if I use virtual for the functions inside the class definition in the library, it seems like I would also want extern to denote that the implementation of the method is elsewhere (otherwise it throws an error that no body is defined)?  Using extern throws a CS0626 warning: "Method, operator, or accessor 'CommunicationData.OpenConnection()' is marked external and has no attributes on it. Consider adding a DllImport attribute to specify the external implementation."  Is it safe to ignore this warning if the implementation is going to be defined the calling application?

Comment: I would define an interface, which implicitly marks every member as abstract virtual.  If you want some implementation in a base class, then use the `abstract` keyword to declare your virtual functions, indicating that the base class has no implementation, it will be provided by the derived class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @numzero that an interface is probably what you are looking for. But if you want to stay closer to the original implementation:

```
public class CommunicationData
{
    public Func<int> OpenConnection { get; set; }       
    //etc
    
    int MaxTransferSize { get; set; }
}
```

Which allows you to do:

```
var data = new CommunicationData();
data.OpenConnection = OpenConnection;
data.OpenConnection();
```

**Using an interface**

```
//in your lib
public interface ICommunicationData
{
    int OpenConnection();
    int CloseConnection();
    int ReadData(byte[] dataBuf, int numBytes);
    int WriteData(byte[] dataBuf, int numBytes);
    int MaxTransferSize { get; set; }
}

//in your app
public class SerialCommunicationData : ICommunicationData
{
    public int MaxTransferSize { get; set; }

    public int CloseConnection()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public int OpenConnection()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public int ReadData(byte[] dataBuf, int numBytes)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public int WriteData(byte[] dataBuf, int numBytes)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}


public class UsbCommunicationData : ICommunicationData
{
    public int MaxTransferSize { get; set; }

    public int CloseConnection()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public int OpenConnection()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public int ReadData(byte[] dataBuf, int numBytes)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public int WriteData(byte[] dataBuf, int numBytes)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do like the idea of keeping it closer to the original implementation.  How would this work for ReadData() where the first argument needs to be ref byte[], a reference to the array that will be receiving incoming bytes?  using ref does not appear to be allowed when using Func<>.

Comment: @K_Trenholm Arrays are always by reference in c#. I still recommend an interface though.

Comment: oh, I had no idea.  I've been using 'ref byte[]' in place of the original C (uint8_t *) arguments for the functions that modify the incoming/outgoing data buffers.  Is using ref byte[] going to throw things off?  Just so that I'm clear: I pass a byte[] to a method, and modify the array values inside the method, it is NOT making a copy of the byte[] and modifying that, but actually modifying the original byte[] passed as an argument?

I will try implementing as an interface as well.  Unfortunately I won't really know if it works as I want until I build and test it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If `OpenConnection` is to be supplied by the application as you write, using `delegate` is the right way probably. Then you need to define these methods in the application and fill the struct.

Alternatively, `CommunicationData` can be made an `interface` that your application or some other class would need to implement, and you will pass *that* to the library functions. Or maybe wrap a library in a class (with `g_comm` becoming a field) and pass the interface only to its constructor.